# Platform::Array<byte>^ to char* - conversion and memory

Tags: arrays, interop, c++-cx

I have a C code that I want to use in my Windows Store C# application. Not very good at C/C++ but can slam in few lines, so I have a problem and a question. One of the C source functions looks like:

```
send_data(const char *data, size_t len)
```

The wrapper method for this send_data C method in the C++/CX wrapper class I try to write has signature of:

```
WrapperClass::send_data(const Platform::Array<byte>^ buff)
```

And here come the questions:

1. How do I convert Platform::Array^ to char* so that I call send_data? Do I need to allocate memory and add NULL to terminate the char* array?
2. When I pass the data from C# as byte[], do I need to then pin it in memory, so that it does not get moved?

Comment: This seems neither like c or c++. Might this actually be c++/cli?

Comment: Source is in C and I try to get the C++CLI part. Edited question for clarity

Comment: @Angew & Kamen Ah, my bad.

Comment: Platform::Array is a native type, the language extension is called C++/CX.   Nothing to do with managed code, nothing needs to be pinned.   You simply create a char* buffer with the *new* operator and copy the bytes.  Don't forget the 0 terminator, just always append it to be sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, to answer my first question - Converting Platform::Array to char* was nothing harder than:

```
const char* data = _strdup((const char*)data->Data);
```

Note, I am using Visual C++ CLI (Visual Studio 2013), so the _strdup is the choice there.

As for the pinning - will see later :)

Comment: This is not CLI, it's C++/CX which shares a lot of syntactic similarity with C++/CLI. As Hans stated above, there's no need to pin anything in C++/CX since there is no garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to [...] add NULL to terminate the char* array?

This depends on what the C `send_data()` function actually sends. Does it send the `0`-terminator? If "Yes", then you either need to provide it or make your sender's implementation append it.